# What are proper scoring and threshold selection rules for multiclassifiers?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, multi-class, threshold, scoring-rules

I am using a neural network with 5 input neurons, 2 hidden layers of about 50 neurons in each layer, and 4 output neurons, trying to classify my 5-dimensional data into 4 different classes.

Currently, I am choosing the network classification for a given example as the that corresponding to the neuron with the highest output and as expected, these results have been less than good.

How would I score my multiclassifier and subsequently choose different thresholds to improve my results?

So far, what I have tried is creating ROC curves by considering each class alone and the other 3 as a negative class, using a simple scoring method of `fp/(1-fp)` and choosing different thresholds for calculating the confusion matrix. How would I choose a score and thresholds that consider all classes rather than just 1 and the negative?

Thanks,
Annika

Answer (score 2):

Train your network to give you *probabilistic* predictions $\hat{p}_{i1}, \dots, \hat{p}_{i4}$ for membership in your four classes of the $i$-th instance.

Then you can use proper [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules) ("scoring rules" in the technical sense; I can't tell whether you are using the term in this sense - take a look at [the tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info) for more info) to assess these. For instance, if the $i$-th instance turns out to belong to class $j(i)$, then the logarithmic score would penalize the corresponding predictions by $-\log(\hat{p}_{i,j(i)})$, and the Brier score would penalize it by $\hat{p}_{i,j(i)}^2$. In each case, smaller is better. You would average these scores over multiple instances $i$ and prefer models with lower average scores.

Once you have well-calibrated probabilistic classifications, you can tune your thresholds for optimality, which will involve not only the predictions, but also the *costs* of misclassification. [See here for more info.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312124/1352) That is, you should separate the *prediction* and the *decision* aspects of your problem.